# How can I get historical data on litecoin prices?

Tags: php

I'm writing a chart program for bitcoins and litecoins.  I cannot figure out a way to get the historical price data for litecoins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LTC-Charts](http://www.ltc-charts.com/) will have this info.